# Plotly table cell color depending on cell data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, plotly

Good day everyone, please can i be assisted in anyway possible. I am trying to code cell colour depending on the answer to my functions.

```
b = df['Supertrend']

a = b[-1]

def main(a):
   if a !=True:
   return 'Bearish'
   else:
   return 'Bullish'

poes = main(a)

j = d1['Supertrend']

k = j[-1]

def main(k):
   if k!= True:
   return 'Bearish'
   else:
   return 'Bullish'

doos = main(k)

l = d15['Supertrend']

m = l[-1]

def main(m):
  if m!= True:
  return 'Bearish'
  else:
  return 'Bullish'

naai = main(m)

n = d1h['Supertrend']

o = n[-1]

 def main(o):
  if o!= True:
  return 'Bearish'
  else:
  return 'Bullish'

tiet = main(o)

q = d1d['Supertrend']

p = q[-1]

 def main(p):
  if p!= True:
  return 'Bearish'
 else:
  return 'Bullish'

kak = main(p)

TF = ['1 Minute', '5 Minutes', '15 Minutes', '1 Hour', 'Daily']
BB = [doos, poes, naai, tiet, kak]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
header=dict(values=[['<b>Timeframe</b>'], ['<b>Bullish/Bearish</b>']],
            line_color='black',
            fill_color='black',
            align='center',
            height= 40,
            font=dict(color='white', size=15)),
```

So i guess here is where I need some help. To dictate that if the function outputs bearish the cell must be red and if it outputs bullish it should be green

```
cells=dict(values=[TF,BB],
           line_color='darkslategray',
           fill = dict(color=['black',
```

I tried the first below but doesnt really work

```
          ['#ff2d5d' if BB == str('Bearish') else '#04b29b']]),
           font=dict(color='white', size=12),
           height = 30,
           align='center'))
           ])

          fig.update_layout(width=500, height=450)
          fig.show()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since if statements cannot be written in the list, it is possible to create a color list in advance and specify it to color-code the cells.

```
TF = ['1 Minute', '5 Minutes', '15 Minutes', '1 Hour', 'Daily']
BB = [doos, poes, naai, tiet, kak]

colors = ['#ff2d5d' if c == 'Bearish' else '#04b29b' for c in BB]
print(colors)
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=[['<b>Timeframe</b>'], ['<b>Bullish/Bearish</b>']],
                line_color='black',
                fill_color='black',
                align='center',
                height= 40,
                font=dict(color='white', size=15)),

   cells=dict(values=[TF,BB],
           line_color='darkslategray',
           fill = dict(color=['black',colors]),
           font=dict(color='white', size=12),
           height = 30,
           align='center'))
           ])

fig.update_layout(width=500, height=450)
fig.show()
```

[image]